# How to automatically trigger click event on a `file input select ` in a bs modal? (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

In a `bootstrap modal` I have a `file select input` which I want to be fired automatically just by opening modal. I tried many many different approaches, but none of them worked for me.

**UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/bocc4f8d/**

```
<div id="cropit" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="close-modal-crop" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ heading_title }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="image-cropper">
                <div class="controls-wrapper text-center" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <input id="cropit-image-input" type="file" class="cropit-image-input custom" accept="image/*">
```

By opening modal, I want `#cropit-image-input` to be clicked automatically.
I'd highly appreciate if you give me a hand.

Comment: You cannot do that without any user interaction (click/mousedown or mouseup). e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/bocc4f8d/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff: Very strange, but why it should be impossible!?

Comment: See dupe link. This is obviously for security reason

Comment: @A.Wolff: That's a very helpful link, thanks a lot!